# matching array items in rails

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to see the total number of matches, between the arrays individual items that their are.

For example arrays with:

1 -- House, Dog, Cat, Car
2 -- Cat, Book, Box, Car

Would return 2.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT/

Basically I have two forms (for two different types of users) that uses nested attributes to store the number of skills they have. I can print out the skills via

```
current_user.skills.each do |skill| skill.name

other_user.skills.each do |skill| skill.name
```

When I print out the array, I get: `#<Skill:0x1037e4948>#<Skill:0x1037e2800>#<Skill:0x1037e21e8>#<Skill:0x1037e1090>#<Skill:0x1037e0848>`

So, yes, I want to compare the two users skills and return the number that match. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
a = %w{house dog cat car}
b = %w{cat book box car}
(a & b).size
```

Documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000274

To convert classes to an array using the name, try something like:

```
class X
  def name
    "name"
  end
end
a = [X.new]
b = [X.new]
(a.map{|x| x.name} & b.map{|x| x.name}).size
```

In your example, a is current_user.skills and b is other_users.skills.  x is simply a reference to the current index of the array as the map action loops through the array.  The action is documented in the link I provided.

Comment: Doing a-b would keep duplicates in there and would return greater for elements that exist in a but not in b, which doesn't sound like what was wanted, although both work for the example data.

Comment: I have created a codepad example to illustrate what I mean.  http://codepad.org/u5FVaPcF

Comment: This looks like the best solution but I'm returning zero -- does my array need to be in a certain format?

Comment: The reason this solution does not work is because the skills are objects which are stored in different memory locations and are therefore not comparable.  You should create an array from the names or ids and use that for comparison.

Comment: Thanks -- anyway you could give me a quick shout out on how to do that?